# JSpinner Arrows in odd positioning when used with JLabel

Tags: java, swing, format, jspinner

Hello So i have created a JFrame with a JSpinner inside (as you can see in the picture). Right now, the BorderLabel is showing in the Jspinner (as it should) but the arrows on the JSpinner are there as a part of the entire thing instead of just the JSpinner field. I would like help to find out how to put the JSpinner arrows on the bar. Thank you.

[image]

For you who asked for code,

Also I miss stated JLabel Earlier. I meant TitledBorder

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class ex extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ex();


    }
    ex(){
        super("test");
        setSize(200,100);
        SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(3,1,25,1);
        JSpinner shiftIn = new JSpinner(sm);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        shiftIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        shiftIn.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new TitledBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,
                0, 0, 0), "Shift Key"), shiftIn
                .getBorder()));
        p.add(shiftIn);
        add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking questions about component positioning and layout, you need to post relevant code, preferably an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Else the question comes a "please guess why the code I'm not showing you is not working" question, questions that are very hard to answer.

Comment: *"JLabel is showing in the Jspinner (as it should)"* - Should it?  That sounds wrong already...

Comment: Please read or re-read the [mcve link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will want to create and post a small program that has no functionality, but that displays your GUI and shows for us your problem. It should be small, simple, and compile and run for us without need of outside images, files, databases, etc.

Comment: Also, you don't want to set preferred sizes of anything and should almost never need to call `updateUI()` in a Swing GUI unless you're changing the look and feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
shiftIn.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
    new TitledBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0), "Shift Key"), 
    shiftIn.getBorder()));
```

[image]

This is not the sort of thing that a titled border was made for!

Use a `JLabel` and put it in the `PAGE_START` of a `BorderLayout`, put the `JSpinner` in the `PAGE_END`.  Add that container (the panel) where the spinner is currently added.  (Then add a mnemonic for the label and make it the 'label for' the spinner.)

---

This is how to use that idea inside another layout (`GridLayout` in this example)..

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ex extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ex();
    }

    ex() {
        super("test");
        // imagine this is actually using GridBagLayout
        JPanel ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3,4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 1, 25, 1);
        JSpinner shiftIn = new JSpinner(sm);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Shift Key"); 
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(l, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        p.add(shiftIn, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(ui);

        for (int ii=0; ii<9; ii++) {
            if (ii==4) {
                ui.add(p);
            } else {
                ui.add(new JButton("Button"));
            }
        }

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes.  Yours is a valid approach, but I'd still prefer to use a label if it is to label a control.  Perhaps use a titled border for a *group of controls* (as [seen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LdJf5.png) in [eJuMiCa](http://forums.aussievapers.com/diy-juice-recipes-mixing/28538-e-juice-mixing-calculator-needs-testing.html)).

Comment: Well the code that I'm using is a part of a much larger program. The panel there has a couple of buttons as well and when I add the JLabel at `PAGE_START` the label just goes to the left of the JSpinner. Also I'm using `GridBagLayout` to layout my swing components but I am not exactly sure how to use GridBagLayout very well.

Comment: @Meeesh *"but I.."* ..forgot to finish that comment?  I have to say, it was not making much sense up to that point.  For further help, it would be better to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of this effect.

Comment: *"Also I'm using GridBagLayout to layout my swing components"*  Stop thinking 'use X layout'.  All GUIs (even if we use a single layout) consist of multiple layouts.  That is what I meant from my comment above about using a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` for the label and spinner.  If you add that ***panel*** where the GBL puts the spinner, it will work as advertised.  I can only guess you tried to add the **label** in the `PAGE_START` of the BGL, which is all kinds of ***not what I meant.***

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be running into risk by messing with the JSpinner's border. Myself, I would wrap my JSpinner in a JPanel and then give that wrapper JPanel the desired border. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Ex extends JFrame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Ex();

   }

   Ex() {
      super("test");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 1, 25, 1);
      JSpinner shiftIn = new JSpinner(sm);
      JPanel spinnerWrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      spinnerWrapper.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0), "Shift Key"));
      spinnerWrapper.add(shiftIn);
      shiftIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
      add(spinnerWrapper);
      pack(); 
      setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay that looks very good however my jpanel there contains multiple buttons as well. Should I just create a separate JPanel or is there a better way.

Comment: *"Should I just create a separate JPanel.."*  Yes!  Nest layouts inside one another for complex layout needs.